# File paths are not working [WinError 2] when trying to get file sizes using the os library

Tags: python

Essentially, I'm comparing pdf's to see if there are duplicates by using something other than their name.  This is because all of the pdf's in my dataset have unique names, but could still be the same thing, content wise.  Seek and destroy the duplicates.  I'm still in the seek part of this project.

I decided to try to compare file sizes first to see what I would find before I tried anything else.  I figured that would be a simple first approach, but for some reason the os library doesn't like the way that I'm feeding it the string of the file path.  I've tried manipulating it any way I can to get it to work, but no dice.

I went through and confirmed that the file exists within the folder I'm trying to get into.

So here is kind of the workflow for how I am imagining this to work.  I pulled a query of the possible drawings that could contain duplicates and saved it as an excel file.  I saved that file as a csv file so if I mess up the sheet I don't mess up my data.  Plus I new a quick way to turn csv file columns into lists using pandas.

[Here is a screen shot of the csv file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j4mBg.jpg)

In the code below you can see that I made a list that has each of those columns. all of the data within the lists are strings.  The description isn't very critical, but the "found in" and "name" columns (When concatenated) make up the file path and file name.   I made a new list of the combined string that is the file path + the file so that I could get its size to compare.

I'm really hoping there is a way I can manipulate that path in either the csv file or in python with the lists.

Here is the error that comes up when I run the code.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZwPEl.jpg

C:\Users\27659\Desktop\PycharmProjects\sort_unique_profiles\venv\Scripts\python.exe "C:/Users/27659/Desktop/PycharmProjects/sort_unique_profiles/Compare and mark files.py"

```
same item in list

Traceback (most recent call last):

    File "C:/Users/27659/Desktop/PycharmProjects/sort_unique_profiles/Compare and mark files.py", line 19, in <module>

        if os.path.getsize(full_file_list[i]) == os.path.getsize(full_file_list[k]) and i == k:

    File "C:\Users\27659\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\genericpath.py", line 50, in getsize

        return os.stat(filename).st_size

FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'C:\\WS\\WS\\Aspire\\CA & AW\\7205\\AW\\85-7535-01.pdf'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

'

Here is the code

```
import pandas as pd
import os


main_df = pd.read_csv("C://Users//27659//Desktop//Unique Wood Profiles.csv")

drawing_number_list = main_df['Name'].tolist()
description_list = main_df['Description'].tolist()
found_in_list = main_df['Found In'].tolist()
full_file_list = ['placeholder']

for i in range(0, len(drawing_number_list)):
    full_file_list.append(found_in_list[i] + drawing_number_list[i] + '.pdf')

del full_file_list[0]

for i in range(0, len(full_file_list)):
    for k in range(0, len(full_file_list)):
        if os.path.getsize(full_file_list[i]) == os.path.getsize(full_file_list[k]) and i == k:
            print('same item in list')
        elif os.path.getsize(full_file_list[i]) == os.path.getsize(full_file_list[i]):
            print('oh bugger')
        else:
            print('thumbs up')
```

Comment: These PDFs you're comparing.. you're looking for exact matches? Like, they would be the exact same file?

Comment: Did you double check that the file exists?

Comment: @cody yes, but the names of the files would be different.  It would be like if you did a save as on the pdf and called it a different name without changing anything else.

Comment: I guess there could be a problem with the escaped backslashes. Try using forward slashes in the paths.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [File Paths, Escape Characters, and OS Library Inputs (Won't Except my File Paths)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53637976/file-paths-escape-characters-and-os-library-inputs-wont-except-my-file-paths)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to modify this line because it's currently comparing it to itself:

```
elif os.path.getsize(full_file_list[i]) == os.path.getsize(full_file_list[i]):
```

To:

```
elif os.path.getsize(full_file_list[i]) == os.path.getsize(full_file_list[k]):
```

Now I would like to suggest a different approach and give you the code to do it.  Instead of bothering with file sizes / dates / whatever just look at the file hashes.

```
import hashlib
import pandas as pd
import os

main_df = pd.read_csv("C://Users//27659//Desktop//Unique Wood Profiles.csv")

drawing_number_list = main_df['Name'].tolist()
description_list = main_df['Description'].tolist()
found_in_list = main_df['Found In'].tolist()
full_file_list = []
file_hashes = dict()

for i in range(0, len(drawing_number_list)):
    full_file_list.append(found_in_list[i] + drawing_number_list[i] + '.pdf')

for file_path in full_file_list:
    file_hash = hashlib.sha256(open(file_path, 'rb').read()).digest()

    if file_hash in file_hashes.keys():
        file_hashes[file_hash].append(file_path)
    else:
        file_hashes[file_hash] = [file_path]

for key, value in file_hashes.items():
    if len(value) > 1:
        print('Duplicates Found')
        print('Hash', key)
        for entry in value:
            print(entry)
        print('-' * 40)
```

Comment: interesting, I'll have to look into hashes.  It's not a subject i'm at all familiar with.  I'll have to make some test data and try this out.  I'll get back to you.